# the rhinos put up with this indignity

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The birds also get nutrients by picking at sores on the rhinos’ bodies. Plotz suspected that the rhinos put up with this **indignity** because the oxpeckers make loud alarm calls whenever they see humans approach—giving the rhinos an early warning to flee.

I don't understand why use indignity here, does rhinos felt shame when the birds picking at his sores? What does the sentence mean？

---

article link : https://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode/birds-on-rhinos-back-help-them-avoid-poachers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course we don't *know* how the rhinos feel about it. The writer is projecting human feelings onto them; we would consider it uncomfortable and undignified to have birds constantly pecking at our skin.

Answer (score 0):

That is the literal meaning.  But it is being used figuratively. It's not a particular idiom, it's something the journalist has created to make the writing more interesting.

We aren't suggesting that rhinos actually feel shame, but that having birds peck at sores is the sort of thing that would make you feel shame, if you could.

It suggests that the birds don't cause physical harm to the rhinos, but that they are annoying.